# Debian: Run unattended upgrades without the risk to destroy boot due to full boot partition

Tags: debian, kernel, unattended-upgrades

When running a Debian system with GPT and UEFI, I often run into the problem that an update fails due to the boot partition filling up with too many kernels. While `apt autoremove --purge` solves that problem quickly, the state between the update and the autoremove command is dangerous, as no bootable image is present and a reboot would result in fatality, with the need to boot a rescue system.

This becomes a problem when using unattended upgrades. I had configured it on a test machine, and after a few months, it caused the boot to break spontaneously.

How can I prevent this from happening? Also, is it safe to upgrade kernels via unattended upgrades?